# Why is stack structure address out-of-bounded in another function

Tags: c, function, stack, scope

The problem has been reduced from a more complex code to these few lines.
The example code runs without complaints on an amd64 platform, but dbx reveals 
an out-of-bounded error. Silent data corruptions occurr on SPARC, that is
contents of out.intnum and ip->intnum are different.
This disappears as soon as structure "out" is not taken
from stack but from static memory. This is surprising to me since I would have
expected that the storage location of "out" was still valid during the execution
of the function "inner". Has anybody an idea about the reason?

Source file stacker.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stacker {
    char somebytes[8];
    int        intnum;
    unsigned char uc1;
    unsigned char uc2;
};

int inner(struct stacker *ip);
int outer(struct stacker *op);
```

Source file stacker.c

```
#include "./stacker.h"

int inner(struct stacker *ip)
{
    char bubble[4096];
    int i;

    i = ip->intnum;
    return(0);
}

int outer(struct stacker *op)
{
    char bubble[4096];
    struct stacker out;

    inner(&out);
    return(0);
}
```

Source file stacktest.c

```
#include "./stacker.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct stacker main_struct;

    outer(&main_struct);
    printf("done\n");
    return(0);
}
```

When run on command line the program simply prints "done".
In dbx the following message shows the problem:

```
(dbx) run
Running: stacktest 
(process id 4092)
RTC: Enabling Error Checking...
RTC: Running program...
Reading disasm.so
Read from out-of-bounded (rob):
Attempting to read 4 bytes at address 0xfffffd7fffdfeb94
    which is 4164 bytes above the current stack pointer
Variable is 'ip'
stopped in inner at line 8 in file "stacker.c"
(dbx) print ip
ip = 0xfffffd7fffdfeb8c
```

Access to structure "out" via pointer ip in function "inner" should be legal.
Initialization of ""struct out" either by memset or member-wise
will not change the picture (tested this).

Comment: Have you tried initializing all your variables? The `i = ip->intnum` read in the `inner` function is technically undefined behavior since it's accessing the uninitialized variable `out`.

Comment: Is it possible that your debugging tool is implementing some very naive rule like "any access to the stack that is more than 4096 bytes above the stack pointer is flagged as out of bounds"?  "out of bounded" is bad grammar too; the correct English is "out of bounds".

Comment: Because, clearly, 4164 bytes above the stack pointer isn't in fact out of bounds. There is over 8 Kb of buffer space.  The diagnostic appears to be correct as far as the displacement calculation: it is believable that the four byte access is 4164 above the stack pointer (i.e. into a stack that grows downward).

Comment: Even if the structure is initialized you will see "out-of-bounded" (tested this). On the other hand: Out-of-bound(ed)/(s) does not mean out of stack but out of object's bounds. Tests have shown that the problem might disappear with a different order of members in struct stacker. The reason is still unclear ...